# How to step through the help() text in Ipython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

When I execute "help(some_module)" in Ipython the window will scroll to the end of the help and unable me to read from the start.

Is there some way of calling the help() function that allows me to view one page at a time? I looked in the Python 2.7 docs for this but there was nothing about it there.

Thanks!

Comment: `J`, `K`, `page up`, `page down`?

Comment: @Fabricator you beat me to it. Also, I would try using hjkl

Comment: Why would you look in the Python2.7 docs, rather than the [IPython docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/shortcuts/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same commands as `less` or `vim`:

- `f` - scroll forward one page
- `b` - scroll backward one page
- `3f` - scroll forward 3 lines (for any n)
- `j` or `down arrow` - scroll down one line
- `k` or `up arrow` - scroll up one line
- `gg` - go to top
- `G` - go to bottom
- `/foo` - go to first instance of word `foo`

etc

For more examples see, `man less`, `man vim`, or `vimtutor`.

To expand on this answer, it really depends on which pager you use, and while `less` is the default pager, you can configure IPython to use a different pager [by setting the `PAGER` environment variable](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.core.page.html?highlight=pager#IPython.core.page.pager_page).

You won't find these keyboard shortcuts in the Python / IPython docs because the pager is a totally separate program.  (I think there's room for the IPython docs to make that more clear.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not clear on the syntax. If I write help(module) f it gives me an error and if I write help(module,j) it says that name j is not defined.

Comment: @gefdel Make sure to import the module first

Comment: @gefdel Feel free to click the green checkmark to accept the answer if you feel I've covered your question.  Thank you!

Comment: Edminston I didn't know about that!